# viewState lost when you click the back button on your browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

First I would like to disregard my bad English, because I'm taking help of google translate;

I am dealing with a report of assembly page that contains the same N div's and a div is handled with UpdatePanel, as you can see in the example below:

```
asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScpManager" runat="server" EnableHistory="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updProcesso" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAcima" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAbaixo" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSelecionar" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDesfazer" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMudaOrdem" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMudaOperacao" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Campos Disponíveis
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstOrigem" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                        Width="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAcima" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mover para Cima"
                        Width="110px" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAbaixo" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mover para Baixo"
                        Width="110px" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSelecionar" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Selecionar"
                        Width="110px" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDesfazer" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Desfazer Seleção"
                        Width="110px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Campos Selecionados
                </td>
                <td>
                    Ordem
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Operação
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstDestino" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                        Width="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstOrdem" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                        Width="50px"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMudaOrdem" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mudar Ordem"
                        Width="95px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstOperacao" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                        Width="115px"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMudaOperacao" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mudar Operação"
                        Width="110px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I found a big problem is that when there is a redirect to the page that generates the report and click on the back of the browser itself is the loss of all parameters to the same non-manipulated with the UpdatePanel, setados to generate the report. What appears to me is the loss of viewState. I tried to implement the

However using the Request page ends up giving postback and is not manipulated the necessary form. I found numerous cases on the internet, no more relevant solution for this case. I would like an idea of how we could overcome this obstacle.

Knowing that the option of implementing the back button on another page bringing the parameters would not be the right solution because it does not prevent the user back by the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

try enabling viewstate on page level add this `EnableViewState="false"` on page header

Comment: Unfortunately there is loss of data in the same way, but the loss occurs even in the own page postbacks.

Comment: Do you run the site on a web farm?